# Is PNC Bank's Virtual Wallet accessible from Android?

Tags: browser

I am a college student in need of a new bank account. PNC Bank's Virtual Wallet service really appeals to me, except I have one unanswered question: Will I be able to keep an eye on it from my Android phone?

Virtually every major bank appears to offer some sort of free downloadable app for Android, but I read comments that the standard PNC Bank app does not work well with, specifically, a Virtual Wallet account, due to it's three-fold Checking-Reserve-Savings system. Nowhere on PNC's website do they clarify this issue.

Seemingly in response to this issue, PNC Bank has published an app specifically for Virtual Wallet customers, but this app appears to be available only on the iPhone, not for Android.

Since a real app does not seem to exist, one might wonder whether the Virtual Wallet website is well-behaved in the standard Android mobile browser, and how much functionality I might be able to expect. There appears to be no way to find out except to open the account first and try it for myself, which is unacceptable, hence my question here.

Can anyone with a PNC Virtual Wallet attempt to log into the administration website from their Android phone (I have a Droid2) and tell me if it's even slightly usable?

Answer (score 2):

It is actually very usable! I use it all the time and am quite pleased with it. The interface is slightly different then the desktop site but you can tell that it was redesigned to run on mobile phones. Just go to PNC.com and log in, it will auto-detect that you are on a mobile browser and load the mobile version of the site. I was a little upset at first that there was no PNC app for Android but after using their mobile site I honestly don't care anymore, it is just as good as a dedicated banking app. Definitely do not make your decision because there is no app the mobile site provides all the info you need, and it doesn't take up space on your phone.

EDIT: I'm on a Droid 1 BTW. Just in case it doesn't auto detect your browser [Here](https://m.pnc.com/alservlet/MobileBrowserServlet) is a link to the mobile site.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HTC incredible and there is currently no v wallet.app for Android. There is a mobile version of the admin site and It works for some basic functionality but does not have all the options v wallet carries. U can get to the regular or full site via the internet but runs slow and is very difficult to manage the v wallet functions. Hope his helps

Comment: I use it all the time and never have problems with speed. other than the nice graphical features what is missing? I noticed the calendar isn't there but you can still see detailed transactions by date. The graphical savings engine isn't there but you can still transfer funds. Also the bill paying part is still there...